# SCORM 2004 Sequencing: What Am I doing wrong?

Tags: scorm

This quiz is the last SCO in a grouping of 4 SCOs. SCO 1,2,3 have to be completed before this quiz becomes available. The problem is that when 1,2,3 are completed the menu skips right over this quiz and goes to the first page in the next module. This quiz stats grayed out the entire time. I think it has to do with the precondition logic or the objectives but I've tried everything I can think of and nothing works.

```
      <item identifier="quiz1_100" identifierref="res-quiz1" isvisible="true">
    <title>Quiz 1</title>
                <imsss:sequencing>
                    <imsss:controlMode choice="true" choiceExit="false" flow="true" forwardOnly="false" useCurrentAttemptObjectiveInfo="false" useCurrentAttemptProgressInfo="false" />
                    <imsss:sequencingRules>


                        <imsss:preConditionRule>
                          <imsss:ruleConditions conditionCombination="any">
                            <imsss:ruleCondition referencedObjective="obj_1000_VHKP_test" operator="not" condition="objectiveStatusKnown" />
                            <imsss:ruleCondition referencedObjective="obj_2000_VHKP_test" operator="not" condition="objectiveStatusKnown" />
                            <imsss:ruleCondition referencedObjective="obj_3000_VHKP_test" operator="not" condition="objectiveStatusKnown" />
                            <imsss:ruleCondition referencedObjective="quiz_primary" operator="not" condition="objectiveStatusKnown" />
                          </imsss:ruleConditions>
                           <imsss:ruleAction action="disabled" />
                        </imsss:preConditionRule>

                       <imsss:preConditionRule>
                         <imsss:ruleConditions conditionCombination="any">
                         <imsss:ruleCondition referencedObjective="obj_1000_VHKP_test" operator="not" condition="objectiveStatusKnown" />
                         <imsss:ruleCondition referencedObjective="obj_2000_VHKP_test" operator="not" condition="objectiveStatusKnown" />
                         <imsss:ruleCondition referencedObjective="obj_3000_VHKP_test" operator="not" condition="objectiveStatusKnown" />
                                  <imsss:ruleCondition referencedObjective="quiz_primary" operator="not" condition="objectiveStatusKnown" />
                         </imsss:ruleConditions>
                            <imsss:ruleAction action="skip" />
                        </imsss:preConditionRule>   

                   <imsss:preConditionRule>
                            <imsss:ruleConditions conditionCombination="all">
                                <imsss:ruleCondition condition="completed" />                                   
                            </imsss:ruleConditions>
                            <imsss:ruleAction action="skip" />
                        </imsss:preConditionRule>   
                    </imsss:sequencingRules> 


                    <imsss:objectives>  

                        <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID="quiz_primary" satisfiedByMeasure="true">
                             <imsss:minNormalizedMeasure>0.8</imsss:minNormalizedMeasure>
                             <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="quiz_complete" writeNormalizedMeasure="true" writeSatisfiedStatus="true" /> 
                         </imsss:primaryObjective>  

                        <imsss:objective satisfiedByMeasure="false" objectiveID="obj_1000_VHKP_test">
                            <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="gObj_1000_VHKP" readSatisfiedStatus="true" readNormalizedMeasure="false" />
                         </imsss:objective>

                        <imsss:objective satisfiedByMeasure="false" objectiveID="obj_2000_VHKP_test">
                            <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="gObj_2000_VHKP" readSatisfiedStatus="true" readNormalizedMeasure="false" />
                        </imsss:objective>

                        <imsss:objective satisfiedByMeasure="false" objectiveID="obj_3000_VHKP_test">
                            <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="gObj_3000_VHKP" readSatisfiedStatus="true" readNormalizedMeasure="false" />
                        </imsss:objective>

                        <!--
                        <imsss:objective satisfiedByMeasure="false" objectiveID="obj_quiz1">
                            <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="quiz_primary" readSatisfiedStatus="true" readNormalizedMeasure="false" />
                        </imsss:objective> -->

                        <imsss:objective satisfiedByMeasure="false" objectiveID="course_complete">
                            <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="obj_EJBOWNADV_primary" readSatisfiedStatus="true" readNormalizedMeasure="false" />
                        </imsss:objective>

                    </imsss:objectives> 

                    <imsss:deliveryControls tracked="true" completionSetByContent="true" objectiveSetByContent="false" />

                </imsss:sequencing>
  </item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your precondition rule that has a skip action is seemingly what is causing the quiz to be skipped over. In looking at that rule, it appears that you will never be able to get into the quiz the first time via flow navigation. That rule will fire if "any" condition evaluates to true. The last condition states that if the primary objective for the quiz has an unknown satisfaction status, the rule should fire. Since you have not yet entered the quiz, it will have an unknown satisfaction status and always be skipped. (This is assuming that the global objective quiz_complete is not written to elsewhere.) You might want to look at the [Post Test Rollup example](http://www.scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples/) at scorm.com for a template of how to implement this sequencing strategy.